# How to pass Event (e) and variables with event listeners?

Tags: javascript

I have an event listener like this:

```
div.addEventListener('mouseover',function(){bubble_info.call(data);},false);

function bubble_info(e,info){
  //get e.pageX etc
  //do stuff with info
}
```

This problem is in `bubble_info` the variable `e` holds the info of `data` and `info` is undefined

How do i make sure i can get `e` and `info` correctly?

Comment: `div.addEventListener('mouseover',function(e){bubble_info.call(this, e,data);},false);`

Comment: Is `this` a necessity for that to work ?

Comment: Yep, `call( this, argx, etc )`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event Object has many useful [properties and methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event).

```
div.addEventListener('mouseover',function(event){
    bubble_info(event, info); 
    // you can pass additional params that can be used in your handler 
},false);

function bubble_info(event, info){
  // you can access type of event from event object's properties
  console.log(event.type);
  console.log(info); // your additional parameter.
};
```

**[addEventListener Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)**

Use call only if you need to pass reference of `this` *(current)* object.
It's syntax will be ...

```
FunctionName.call(thisArg, arguments-list, ...);
```

**[call Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this (you don't need the call unless you're passing a specific `this` reference - which you're missing in your code anyway):

```
div.addEventListener( 
  'mouseover', 
  function(event) { 
    bubble_info( event, dataYouWant );
  }, 
  false 
}
```

For reference, a .call() should look like this: `bubble_info.call( this, event, etc )`